Getting Error while using error class to handle global error handling in express
I am a newbie to express and have one error while handling an error using a custom class for error and middleware.
app.error.ts
export class AppError extends Error {
  statusCode: number;
  constructor(message: string, statusCode: number) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

Below is the code of the controller in which I am using this class
export const chat = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { prompt } = req.body;
  if (!prompt) 
      {
         // Here I am using this AppError class and getting an error which is given below.
         return next(new AppError("Prompt is required", 400));
      }

  try {
    // Here are some asynchronous tasks...

    const responseText = 'Response Text';

    const response: IResponse<string> = {
      success: true,
      data: responseText,
    };

    return sendResponse(res, response, HttpStatus.OK);
  } catch (error: any) {
    // I tried getting an error in catch also but the same issue occurs
    return next(new AppError(error.message, 500));
  }
};

I am getting the error where I've commented and error is
Error: Prompt is required
    at E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\src\controllers\chat.controller.ts:11:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\src\controllers\chat.controller.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\src\controllers\chat.controller.ts:4:12)
    at chat (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\src\controllers\chat.controller.ts:9:79)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\vibe-ai\vibe-ai-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

and I've used error middleware like this in main app
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import HttpStatus from "http-status-codes";

config();
import { errorMiddleware } from "./src/middlewares";
import { chatRouter } from "./src/routes";
import { AppError } from "./src/utils";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6050;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(here route to the controller);

app.all("*", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  return next(new AppError("Route not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
});

app.use(errorMiddleware);

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`App is listening at port http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);

error.middleware.ts
const errorMiddleware = (err: AppError, req: Request, res: Response) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || SystemConstants.WENT_WRONG;

  const response: IResponse<undefined> = {
    success: false,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack,
  };

  return res.status(err.statusCode).json(response);
};

What I tried...
I've tried to put some consoles everywhere but after the error at controller, it's not coming to the middleware. Although I tried putting the console in AppError and got the logs there.
Also, I tried using throw new AppError() but then I got to know that it won't work in asynchronous tasks.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

It works fine for me. Can't reproduce. The error comes to the error handler middleware. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@LinDu I've used the same code in my another project and shockingly it's working fine over there but in my main project it's not working

Can you create a minimal reproducible and provide the GitHub repo link?

@LinDu, thanks for the time, I got the solution and I posted it in answers. by the way, I can't figure out if you've used my code then how it worked in your system.

Lately, I got to know that error middleware should have all four parameters, error, req, res, and next.
I tried to use all four in params and it worked...
error.middleware.ts
const errorMiddleware = (err: AppError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || SystemConstants.WENT_WRONG;

  const response: IResponse<undefined> = {
    success: false,
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack,
  };

  return res.status(err.statusCode).json(response);
};

